# Should ignoring tag [foo] also hide [foo-bar] and [bar-foo] tags?

Tags: support, ignored-tags

I have added the tag `nhibernate` to my "Ignored Tags" list but I still see questions with the tags `nhibernate-mapping` and `fluent-nhibernate`.

Is there anyway I can ignore all questions with any tag containing the term `nhibernate`?

Comment: Every tag had own existence. You have to add those tags in "Ignored Tags" list for ignoring. Or use wild cards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use wildcards when adding tags to your list. In your case, add `*nhibernate*` to your ignore list.

Comment: that's worked thanks. I'll accept as answer when I'm able to.